# Playwright - JS - Accessing objects/variables created in another JS file

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright, playwright-test

I'm using Playwright as my automation tool.
I've defined objects in a dedicated JS file like in the following example:

//UserObjects.js :

```js
let userObject1 = {


    section1: {
        properties1: {
            propery1: "property1",
            
        },

        properties2: {
            property1: "property1", 
            property2: "property2",
        },
    },

    section2: {
        properties1 : {
            property1: "property1",
        },
    },
   
    sharedFunctions : {
        
        propertyFunction : function()
        {
            // Implementation
        },

    }

}
```

I want to use the previously defined object in the test file: test.spec.js:

```js
test.describe('Tests group1',async () => {
   
    test('one', async ({ page }) => {
        

      
    });
  
    test('two', async ({ page }) => {
     



    });
  });
```

I want to update the same object sequentially as the tests run.
I've tried to use module.exports and try to access the object from the spec file but it treats it as undefined.

Another thing I tried is to create a copy of the object in the code block of test.describe() using :
// test.spec.js:
Before the test.describe(), I've required the object from the file:

```js
const {userObject} = require('../userobjects/UserObjects.js');
```

And then created a copy of the object, but it still does treats it as undefined:

```js
    let user1 = Object.assign({}, userObject);
```

After performing the following in UserObjects.js :

```js
module.exports.getEmployee = {userObject};
```

One more question, what practice is better? Accessing the object in the external file or creating a copy inside the test.describe()?
Thanks